# Unable to send the mail using php in fedora 23?

Tags: php, laravel, yii, fedora, fedora-23

I am unable to send the mail using PHP mail function in fedora 23.I am getting error as :

```
==> error_log <==
mkdir: cannot create directory '/.esmtp_queue': Permission denied
/usr/sbin/sendmail: line 83: return: can only `return' from a function or  sourced script
```

Comment: The error text explains everything. So you try to create `/.esmtp_queue` folder and check sending mail.

Comment: i have tried but now i am getting the error as :                                       ==> error_log <==
   /bin/mktemp: failed to create directory via template '/.esmtp_queue   /XXXXXXXX': Permission denied
/usr/sbin/sendmail: line 83: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script

Comment: You need to change the permission of the directory and enable others to create files inside. Like this `sudo chmod -R 777 /.esmtp_queue`. I haven't work with fedora, it's from ubuntu, syntax may vary.

Comment: Hi i tried by doing as you suggested but still i end up with error :                   ==> error_log <==
/usr/sbin/sendmail: line 64: /.esmtp_queue/XXXXXXXX/cmd: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/sendmail: line 64: /.esmtp_queue/XXXXXXXX/mail: No such file or directory
[Tue Mar 08 03:17:04.161211 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1394] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart

Comment: See, errors are changing.

Comment: ya did, now i am getting error as ==> error_log <==
No configuration file found at (null) or /etc/esmtprc

Comment: Hm... `/etc/esmtprc` must be a config file with your email server settings. Like this: `hostname = mymail.servere.com:25 username = "myself" password = "secret" starttls = disabled mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"`